# Pascal: Pointer to an array of unknown size?

Tags: arrays, pointers, dynamic, pascal, lazarus

I struggling with Pascal (using Lazarus) at the moment....

I am trying to set set up a system for populating a combobox based on const records. In these is a pointer to an array of strings. The idea being that at runtime I can modify the UI just by selecting a different record.

My problem is that this all works if I define the size of the string array in the record definition. But I don't want to do that as it will vary. I tried to use a dynamic array but got an exception.

Pointers (!) on what I am doing wrong will be gratefully received ;)

Hopefully this code snippet explains better what I am doing.....

```
type
  // definition of the record used for setting the combo box
  TComboItemsTextArray = array[0..10] of string[25]; // this works but I don't want to define the arrray size here.....
  // TComboItemsTextArray = array of string;         // this alternative gives an exception.

  TQDef = record
    ......
    Min : Integer;            
    Max : Integer;            
    ComboItemTextArray : ^TComboItemsTextArray;  
    ........
  end;

const
  // example text array for a specific combo setup
  Names : array[1..5] of string[25] =
  (
    'Name 1',
    'Name 2',
    'Name 3',
    'Name 4',
    'Name 5'
  );

  // specific combo box setup record
  QDef1 : TQDef =
  ( 
    ......
    Min:1;
    Max:5;
    ComboItemTextArray:@Names;
    .....
  );


var
  Q : TQDef;  
  I : Integer;
  ...
begin

  // set the question to be used
  Q := Qdef1;


  // use array to setup combo box
  for I := Q.Min to Q.Max do
    QCombo.Items.Add(Q.ComboItemTextArray^[I]);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In FPC and D2009+ a pointer to X can be overindexed as an array. But these kind of hacks are not terribly nice.

Create the datastructure runtime from various unlinked arrays is the easiest alternative. More advanced is going into the direction of resources.

Comment: Can you explain overindex to me? I guess you were talking about using a plain pointer but treating it as an array so I changed the definition of ComboItemTextArray  to ComboItemTextArray : Pointer; That just gave me a compile error :(

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, but the element type must still match, so ^single can be treated as array of single etc. So in your case probably ^string[25]

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't quite say this, but I took away that you are trying to define the size of the array dynamically.  This can be done like so:

```
type
  // definition of the record used for setting the combo box
  TComboItemsTextArray = array[0..10] of string[25]; // this works but I don't want to define the arrray size here.....
  // TComboItemsTextArray = array of string;         // this alternative gives an exception.

      TQDef = record
        ......
        Min : Integer;            
        Max : Integer;            
        ComboItemTextArray : ^TComboItemsTextArray;  
        ........
      end;

    ...

        var
          Q : TQDef;
          length : integer;

          length := 20; // Arbitrary length...
          SetLength(Q.ComboItemTextArray, length)
```

Comment: Assuming that the Pascal that you are using has dynamic arrays and a SetLength function, of course.

Comment: I think this is what confuses me. I though that CombItemTextArray was pointing to a properly defined array (ie that defined in the const QDef1) so why am I having to set the length at runtime?

Comment: btw. It is not that I want to define the size of the array dynamically. I don't actually care what size it is. I just be want to be able to use different length  const arrays to populate a combo box. You might have guessed that I normally use C and Pascals strong typing is confusing me.....